# Android application with arguments via manifest

Tags: android, arguments, apk, manifest, autostart

I have an application built to PC(.exe) and android(.pak), when executing in the PC I pass the arguments via shortcut + -RCWebControlEnable. It works perfectly.
Unfortunately, this cannot be directly replicated in android. How Am I supposed to do this? Via manifest, correct? But where exactly and in which field should it be inserted, and how?

like this:  ?
is it beeing automatically called? and where do I place it, in the  intent filetr? which one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by _"pass the arguments"_ (who/what is going to pass them?). But if e.g. you start your app's main activity with something like `adb shell am start -n com.example.myapp/.MainActivity --es "param1" "Hello"` then you'd be able to get the string `"Hello"` inside your activity by `intent.getStringExtra("param1")`.

Comment: You can launch an intent with parameters, but you can't force the launcher app to launch you with specific parameters.  If you need that, the only thing I can think of is to create a specific wrapper Activity that acts as your intent filter, and the only thing it does is launch the intent you really want to run with parameters then finish()